# PDO bindValue does not escape

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Something weird is happening because PDO should escape any XSS

Here is my PDO Class

```
<?php
class Database {
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $user = 'root';
    private $pass = '';
    private $dbname = '';

    private static $_instance;

    private $dbh;
    private $stmt;
    private $error;

    private function __construct() {
        if($this->dbh != null)
            return $this->dbh;

        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING, //ERRMODE_SILENT
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
        );
        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '__construct -> ';
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    private function __clone(){
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!self::$_instance) {
            self::$_instance = new Database();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function query($query) {
        try {
            $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'query -> ';
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function bindValue($param, $value, $type) {
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }
    public function execute() {
        try {
            return $this->stmt->execute();
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'execute -> ';
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
?>
```

...and here is a handler to insert comments into database

```
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `comments` (`user_id`, `post_id`, `text`, `added`) VALUES (:user_id, :post_id, :text, :added)");
        $this->db->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $this->db->bindValue(':post_id', $recipe_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $this->db->bindValue(':text', $_POST['text'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $this->db->bindValue(':added', time(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $this->db->execute();
```

and the input is not escaped by "">'>''>"> alert(1);"

[image]

...so what's wrong with PDO ??

Comment: PDO does not escape for anything but SQL context (if at all).

Comment: You must escape your output. There is no reason for PDO not to save the string `"">'>''>"> alert(1);"`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic stackoverflow removed <script> tags... oh.. get it! thanks

Comment: There's no reason for PDO not to save it with <script> tags. It's just a string. You must escape it when outputting using something like `htmlspecialchars` in order to prevent this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing different types of security vulnerability, which have the same basic principle, but happen in different places:

- SQL Injection occurs when an attacker tricks your code into building an SQL string that has side effects on your data. For instance, executing a DROP TABLE statement by manipulating a dynamic WHERE clause.
- HTML Injection occurs when an attacker tricks your code into building HTML which contains additional elements you didn't intend, possibly including script execution on the user's browser.
- JS Injection again follows a similar pattern when you are dynamically building JS itself.

The mitigation against all of these is similar - to either isolate data from code, so that it can never be executed, or to escape special characters that would "break out of" the intended markup. But there is no single set of escapes that will make a string safe for all contexts, you have to prepare it in the right way for the context you're using it in.

So in your case, the use of parameterised queries in the DB layer prevents SQL Injection, but it has no bearing on how that data will be included in HTML, JS, or even future SQL calls - the text that comes out is identical to the text that goes in.